# Bind ICommand to parent ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have two user controls `LeftPanel` and `DeviceList`.  `DeviceList` is inside the `LeftPanel`.  I want the context menu in device list to be able to call a command on the parent view model, which is set on a grid that hosts `DeviceList`.  I have tried the following but it does not work.

Here is the ContextMenu within `DeviceList`

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type local:LeftPanel}},
                    Path=DeviceListViewModel.RemoveDevice}">
```

Here is the `LeftPanel` usercontrol

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tool.LeftPanel" .... >
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding DeviceListViewModel}" Grid.Column="1">
        <local:DeviceList Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
```

Comment: I'd say don't do this. have your `DeviceListView` invoke a Command in `DevicelistViewModel` and send a "message" from that VM to it's parent VM and act accordingly. don't go down the route of tying View's across multiple VM's. Gets very confusing soon

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the ContextMenu does not see the DataContext of the ViewModel or the Parent. 
A possible solution is here [Access ViewModel / DataConext inside ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823994/access-viewmodel-dataconext-inside-contextmenu) .

Answer (score 0):

the contextmenu is not part of the visualtree, so i think your binding is simply wrong because the datacontext is not what you think of.

use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check your DataContext and bindings at runtime

i assume that you have to work with PlacementTarget in your bindings